# Storing 'date' attribute for ExactTarget subscribers

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, date

I've been trying to store 'Date' via API, but somehow it doesnt work

I have created new field in profile management, called 'prospect_date'

If I create new subscriber, pass all attributes via API without specifing `prospect_date` (attribute/value) , in ET it successfully creates a row without `prospect_date`, which is right

If I create new subscriber, pass all attributes and also `{"Name"=>"prospect_date", "Value"=>"2014-01-24 23:46:13 UTC"}`, in ET it successfully creates a row BUT the `prospect_date` doesn't get stored properly, somehow it stores today's date

Also I tried this one too, still doing the same thing. `{"Name"=>"prospect_date", "Value"=>"24/01/2014"}`

I'm guessing I need to pass with specific format, or by default it will store today's date, do you know format should I use?

Comment: Make sure not to leave your question open - if it's solved, select the checkbox as answered. If it is unresolved, let me know how else I can help.

Comment: Please be sure to mark your question answered. This will help the rest of the community.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/)

> Attributes of a date type will accept dates in various formats, such
>   as 1/1/2005 or January 1, 2005. All dates are stored in the format
>   MM/DD/YYYY, and if a date is entered in a different format, the system
>   will convert it to the proper format when storing it.

I believe `2014-01-24 23:46:13 UTC` fails because it's not expecting a UTC time, and `24/01/2014` fails because the format is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When passing it, try using XSD Date Format, so instead of "2014-01-24 23:46:13 UTC", it woudl look like "2014-01-24T23:46:13Z".

The Z indicates that it is UTC time. If you want to pass the value with a specific offset then you can replace Z with the offset, for example: "2014-01-24T23:46:13-05:00".